# <AntDesing:Input type="text"/> allow only positive integer or decimal values.in Blazor C#

Tags: antd, blazor-webassembly, ant-design-blazor

I am using AntBlazor input type text using Asp.net Core and C#. My requirement is that the input text accepts values from 0 to 25 (only integers and decimal values). Example:

- 5
- 1.002
- 2.054
- 24.0009

Input text should not accept negative values. Example:

- -5
- -21
- -1.023

`<AntDesing:Input type="text"/>` allow only positive integer or decimal values.in Blazor C#